# How do you display lines when printing an outlook task list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using the outlook task list and have created a couple of custom views. I can print them without issue using the table style but the lines between the individual items do not print. Is there an option for this?

Is there a way to create my own style?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is right click on one of the subject headers e.g. "subject":

1. Click "View Settings"
2. Click "Other Settings"

Change Grid lines and Group Headings to the style you want.